# Apply CSS based on certain characters in div / table

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have a php function that pulls my csv data and display it as a table on a web page, something very simple!

My question is, is it possible to have a php code or javascript that scans my table td and if the td ends in a certain character/flag/word, then apply a certain CSS to that td?

I want this so I can apply different css images and colors to my td's depending on the character at the end!

Comment: If you're already using PHP, why not just use PHP to scan the contents and inject the class that way?

Comment: To clarify - this html:  `<tr><td>myFirst</td><td>mylast</td><tr>` Do you mean by character at the end the cell value in the last table cell (meaning `myLast`) or only the last character (meaning `t`)?

Comment: @AlexMorrise i agree that php would be the easier / better option. OP was asking for a javascript or php solution. Your link points to a css only solution - not the same.

Comment: I honestly do not care if it can be done in php/js/css, my php function pulls data from many CSV files, merges them all together as one csv and display them in a table format! i wanted to style my table a bit nicer by selecting if a tr/td has a predefined value, then apply a certain class to that tr/td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is javascript solution based on last character and test only for two variations, basically it takes last character from table cell text content and checks it against another character. For more options I would use switch.

http://jsfiddle.net/xqKvp/

You can change css classes with className property instead of changing inline styles.

```
element.className = 'myClass';
```

There are also numerous options for checking with regular expressions methods or other string object methods, depending on your needs.

Comment: this seems like exactly what I want, except it is not working on my end for some reason, could it be because I am populating my data dynamically from fgetcsv function?

Comment: if you're not changing your html dynamically with ajax, it should work, but be sure that js is placed after the table in document - if it comes sooner, the elements that it works on are not in the dom yet.

Comment: ugh! the elements are changing dynamically! thats probably why! and I did place it at the end of the doc!

Comment: I just created an extra tr to my dynamic table, it worked on the extra static one, but the dynamic ones did not apply ;( any work around this? Otherwise, this would be perfect

Comment: make it a function and call it when you add to your table - in ajax callback for example

Comment: Thank you for the help magyar1984, I got it to work perfect now